# Как узнать кординаты вокруг других кординат на краях поля?

Tags: c#

У меня есть поле в длину 15, в высоту 11. Мне нужно узнать кординаты всех 8 ближайших клеток. То-есть получится вот так:

```
8,8   9,8  10,8 | x-1,y-1 x,y-1 x+1,y-1 

8,9   ---  10,9 | x-1,y    y x    x+1,y

8,10 9,10 10,10 | x-1,y+1 x,y+1 x+1,y+1
```

Но что делать если нужно будет получить относительно Края/угла поля?

```
14,8   15,8  0,8 | x-1,y-1 x,y-1 ???,y-1 

14,9   ---   0,9 | x-1,y    y x    ???,y

14,10 15,10 0,10 | x-1,y+1 x,y+1 ???,y+1
```

Comment: Не понял, какую именно задачу надо решить. Прибавить 1 можете, а прибавить или вычесть 2 что мешает?

Comment: @aepot у меня возникла проблема, немогу составить универсальную формулу для поиска кординат. По сути у меня поле сшито сомо с собой. То-есть верх сшит с низом, а левая сторона сшита с правой и на оборот.